# Highstock: animate chart update when scrollbar is dragged or navigator handle is released

Tags: highcharts

I would like to animate the highstock chart as the scrollbar is being moved and to animate  the update of the chart when a handle on the scrollbar is dragged and then released ( see google finance chart). I have tried setting the animation on both the chart object as well as the plot->series->animation . The chart animates as it loads but doesn't when the scrollbar is updated ( it just gives a jarring update ).

Does this functionality currently exist, or is it in the works for the high stock library?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not possible, but you can suggest it in our uservoice system available here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Comment: I'm confused: someone has already added that idea to your uservoice system, and (as of Feb 25 2013) the uservoice system said that the idea has been implemented and would be rolling out in a few weeks. Has the roll-out just not quite happened yet? Is it about to roll-out? Thanks. http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2142483-graph-display-doesn-t-update-when-the-navigation-s